# Science fiction novel involving humans colonizing an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

I had thought the title was either "Children of Eve" or "Eve's Children" but searching turns up several books with those titles, none of these are the right one.

These are the plot details I can recall:

1. Some sort of environmental breakdown had occurred on Earth long before the events of this story.  Whatever it was hadn't happened quickly, though, as the human race had time to establish a project that took YEARS to prepare for, which involved sending ships out into space to settle humanity on other worlds.
2. We know the project took years to develop, as the main character remembers her parents working on it when she was a child.
3. The plan was to send carefully selected crews on these ships, in suspended animation, along with a cargo of human DNA.
4. Something went wrong with this particular ship and main character (Eve?) was the only crewmember to survive the suspension process, she then had to basically rear her ship's contingent of children by herself.

---

Here are the titles I found on searching which are NOT the book I am looking for:

- *The Children of Eve* by Tim Bishop
- *Children of Eve* by Kevin Casey
- *Children of Eve* by Isabel Constance Clarke.
- *Children of Eve* by Jerry Monroe
- *Children of Eve* by M. D. Poole
- *Children of Eve* by Deirdre Purcell
- *Eve's Children* by Robert J. Fortin
- *Eve's Children* by Hank Garner
- *Eve's Children: The Biblical Stories Retold* by Gerard P. Luttikhuizen
- *Eve's Children: The Return to Africa* by Sharon L. Flin

Comment: So did they actually make it to a planet? Is 'Eve' rearing a bunch of kids on an alien world or are they still shipboard?

Comment: Google was not a the best place to search for SF, especially for this title. On the other hand, ISFDB had only short stories for either title, both in anthologies.

Comment: Danny3414: they were on some planet.  That much I am sure of.  The ship may have crashed, not sure.  That could have been how all the crew died except Eve

Comment: I have edited the titles which it isn't into the question body, could you [edit] any additional info into the question you may have such as your reply to Danny3414?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possibly [Eve's Rib by Bryn Chandler](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1812540.Eve_s_Rib).

[image: Eve's Rib]

I have the book though I don't recall ever reading it (I probably got it as part of a job lot) so I can't comment from direct knowledge of the book. However the summary on Google Books sounds very like your description:

> A thousand of the finest humans are chosen to flee war-torn Earth where the death knell rings for mankind, but only Eve survives the journey. When the ship's computers create new children, Eve vows to teach them only peace and dignity - until challenged by the very embodiment of evil.

Comment: that does seem to be it John Rennie. :) thanks :) :)

Comment: Before I scrolled down to this answer, I was thinking of offering a comment about Eric Flint's *Mother of Demons.* Not a perfect fit for the listed parameters, but fairly close. Looks like I don't need to bother now!

Comment: I had thought it was, perhaps, Seven Eves by Neal Stephenson.